# where,are the URLs to attached product file?

Tags: magento-1.9

I exported "all" product data using the System/data flow profiles/export all products tool from Magento backend manager. Yet, while there were nearly all, there was no column to indicate the attached file that you sometimes want to join to your product when you are creating one.

I have found the directory where all those files are> media/amfiles/files but I need the url of the product to their respective pdf files

Answer (score 0):

I have found it in one table called:

```
am_file
```

the table is quite helpful as it contains a column directly linking to entity_id of products table